# EdgeStyle in GraphPlot

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

I am trying to change the thickness of each edge according to its weight using GraphPlot but it doesnt seem to work.

```
Here's the code I was trying:
edges = {0 -> 1, 0 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 
   2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 
   3 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 
   4 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 10, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 11, 
   4 \[DirectedEdge] 12, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 13, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 14, 
   5 \[DirectedEdge] 15, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 16, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 17, 
   6 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 7 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 
   9 \[DirectedEdge] 10, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 11, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 12, 
   9 \[DirectedEdge] 13, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 14, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 11, 
   10 \[DirectedEdge] 12, 10 \[DirectedEdge] 13, 
   10 \[DirectedEdge] 14, 11 \[DirectedEdge] 12, 
   11 \[DirectedEdge] 13, 12 \[DirectedEdge] 14, 
   15 \[DirectedEdge] 16, 15 \[DirectedEdge] 17, 
   16 \[DirectedEdge] 17, 17 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 16 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 
   16 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 16 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 16 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 
   16 \[DirectedEdge] 11, 16 \[DirectedEdge] 13, 
   16 \[DirectedEdge] 14, 16 \[DirectedEdge] 10};
bin = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 7, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 
   2, 4, 7, 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 
   2, 2};
weights = bin/100;
GraphPlot[edges, 
  EdgeStyle -> Thread[edges -> (Thickness[#] & /@ weights)]]
LayeredGraphPlot[edges, 
 EdgeStyle -> Thread[edges -> (Thickness[#] & /@ weights)]]
```

It works with

```
Graph[edges, 
 EdgeStyle -> Thread[edges -> (Thickness[#] & /@ weights)]]
```

But it is not really What I needed since I had to move the nodes to have a better angular view...etc. 
I also need to put vertex label which again doesn't seem to work whenever I put weights(edge thickness).

So here's a photo of what im trying to achieve with a bit more changes, like weight and better angular view on edges: 
[image: photo1]

I was able to produce one with weights but I cant move the nodes to lessen the cross overs and I cant add the node labels at the same time. 
This is how it looks like:
 [image: with weights]

Comment: do you get what you need if you add the option `PlotTheme->"Classic"` or `PlotTheme->"ClassicLabeled"`?

Comment: ClassicLabeled seems to work for vertex labels. However, I need the weights to show in the thickness of the edges.

Comment: change 0 -> 1 to 0 \[DirectedEdge] 1 or 0 \[UndirectedEdge] 1 works

Comment: I've actually got no problem in that. Im looking for a way to change edge thickness in graphPlot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the option `PlotTheme -> "ClassicLabeled"` we get a graphics object that allows you to move vertices around.

```
GraphPlot[edges, 
  EdgeStyle -> Thread[edges -> (Directive[Gray, Arrowheads[{{5 #, .7}}], 
    Thickness[#]] & /@ weights)],
  PlotTheme -> "ClassicLabeled"]
```

[image]

Using  a layout such as `"RadialEmbedding"` or `"SpringEmbedding"` we get straight edges which makes it easier to change the location of vertices without having to move many points on the incident edges:

```
GraphPlot[edges, 
  EdgeStyle -> Thread[edges -> (Directive[Gray, Arrowheads[{{5 #, .7}}], 
        Thickness[#]] & /@ weights)],
  PlotTheme -> "ClassicLabeled", 
  GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding"]
```

[image]

With `GraphLayout -> "RadialEmbedding"` we get

[image]

Comment: Note: `0 -> 1` in `edges` in OP is replaced with `0 \[DirectedEdge] 1` as suggested by halmir in comments.